Nombre de entorno conda
Al crear un entorno de conda no se guarda con el nombre. Al ejercutar conda info --envs se printea la ruta al final de la cual aparece el hombre pero en el nombre del env aparece un *. Supongo que como consecuencia, cuando lanzo un jupyter nb no me reconoce este entorno como kernell. Como puedo hacer?
